# SQL select two rows from same table (same column, in fact), based on join with other table

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables: `votes` and `submissions`. `votes` stores all the received votes (each person can give a first and second vote), `submissions` holds the items people can vote for. Each item has its own ID. The `votes` table stores the ID of each vote. I want to retrieve the names of the items people votes on. Here's an example of what the tables look like:

`votes:`

```
**voter** | **vote1_ID** | **vote2_ID**
   Foo    |       1      |       2
   Bar    |       3      |       2
   Mark   |       2      |       3
```

`submissions:`

```
**ID** | **name**
   1   |   John
   2   |   Jane
   3   |   Mary
```

I already stated I want to retrieve both the name associated with the first vote and the name associated with the second vote within one query (in fact, I don't really care how many queries it takes, but a single query is always nicer and cleaner of course). How would I go on doing this? I already tried figured I need to use a join, but I can't figure out how to retrieve the value from a same column twice.

**EDIT**: I figured giving an example of what query I'm trying to perform might be useful:

For example, if I want to see what Bar has voted for, the result of the query should be submissions.name twice. In the result of Mark, this is Jane and Mary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `join` the submissions table twice to get the expected result.

```
select v.voter, s1.name, s2.name 
from votes v 
join submissions s1 on v.vote1_id = s1.id
join submissions s2 on v.vote2_id = s2.id
```

Comment: I don't necessarily need v.voter. Is this required for the way you built up your query?

Comment: no..you can remove it from the `select` if you don't need it.

Comment: That feels rather counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

You can do two inner joins to select the separate values.

```
SELECT s1.name, s2.name 
FROM votes v
INNER JOIN submissions s1 ON v.vote1_ID = s1.ID
INNER JOIN submissions s2 ON v.vote2_ID = s2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you want rows instead of columns, you could do two joins and union them together:

```
select v.voter, s1.name
from votes v 
join submissions s1 on v.vote1_id = s1.id
UNION ALL
select v.voter, s2.name
from votes v 
join submissions s2 on v.vote2_id = s2.id
```